# multiple insert in rest service

Tags: json, rest

i have created a rest service int dotnet which inserts one data at a time from an android client(as json format).. is it possible to insert multiple data from android client to my rest service??

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason you cannot POST a list of items to a resource called `/items`.

Comment: is tat possible to get list of items in a json object and insert via rest service into DB?.. because as of now i can insert a individual object... so is it possible to insert multiple object using IList!!